# Find lowest value from the rows which contains similar foreign key value

Tags: mysql, optimization

Table:
**pk   fk   price**
1      1      23
2      1      12
3      1      3
4      2      53
5      2      75
6      3      95
7      3      113
8      3      63
9      3      73
10     3      93
11     4      113
11     4      150
11     4      105

In the above table:
How to find out the lowest price based on it's common **fk** value.
For example: lowest **price** for fk=1 is 3, for fk=2 is 53, for fk=3 is 63 and for fk=4 is 105.

I want a single SQL statement which could find lowest price for each common **fk** value.

Comment: The pks aren't, well, p

Answer (score 1):

You just want a basic aggregate per group.

```
select fk, min(price)
  from your_table
  group by fk;
```